# wordpress: load my webfont instead of google-font?

Tags: wordpress, function, webfonts

I'm tinkering in my WordPress-Theme, again...

Would it make sense to load and register my own font instead of google's, since I use mine but don't use theirs?

I thought I'd just tweak the theme I run, and replace the

```
function load_fonts() {
      wp_register_style('myFont', 'url_to_myFont's_CSS_stored_locally');
      wp_enqueue_style( 'myFont');
   }
```

I am not sure if this could work with the font's styles (light, light-italic etc.)

Thanks for hints and insights!
david

Answer (score 1):

Generally themes use [Google's font repository](https://www.google.com/fonts) to load 'custom' fonts for the theme. You absolutely can replace it with a font of your own choosing - but it probably makes sense to check if it already exists within Google's repo before hard coding your own path. It could potentially speed up loading times if someone has already visited a website that uses said font, although I suppose this is less likely than the popular JS libraries.

If you do provide your own font, make sure you have it under an appropriate license, and are legally allowed to.

Comment: Thanks, Enigma. I bought the font's license, so it is ok to use it I guess. My question went more in the direction of "would it make sense to use the `function load_fonts()` for registering a webfoot stored on my server (instead of calling it with `@font-face` )